# Test two integers to determine if it is day or night

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm working on a project that uses data from the national weather service. One application is determining whether it is day or night (from the data - not from the user's location)

**My question is: I can't understand why the code I've written always returns that it is night!**

I have a property:

```
BOOL isNight;
```

And some variables:

```
int sunriseDifference
int sunsetDifference
```

That represent the difference between the time of observation at the weather station and the local sunset or sunrise at that weather station.

My logic goes like this:

sunriseDifference > 0 AND sunsetDifference > 0 then it is night (PM night)

OR

sunriseDifference < 0 AND sunsetDifference < 0 then it is night (AM night)

Otherwise, it is day.

Here's the code:

```
if ((sunriseDifference >= 0) && (sunsetDifference >= 0)) {
    self.isNight = YES;
} else if ((sunriseDifference <= 0) && (sunsetDifference <= 0)) {
    self.isNight = YES;
} else self.isNight = NO;
```

This always yields

```
self.isNight = YES
```

Any ideas where my mistake is?

**EDIT**

To make it clear, sunriseDifference and sunsetDifference are int's representing # of minutes since either sunset or sunrise.

So at 1500, at a weather station in California (daytime) the values of the variables are:

```
sunriseDifference = 482
sunsetDifference = -118
```

So, according to my logic, neither of the conditions above is satisfied, and thus     self.isNight should be NO. My code returns self.isNight as YES...

I conclude I've made an error in the code, not my logic. Any ideas?

Comment: You treat night when both `sunriseDifference` and `sunsetDifference` are zero or positive or when both are negative. You only treat it as day when one is negative and one is zero or positive. So check your calculations for the two values and see why both are alway positive or both are always negative.

Comment: Just checking, but did you make sure you have data with sunriseDifference and sunsetDifference with different signs?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what sunset and sunrise difference represent?

Comment: So for what data exactly it is not working ? Print values of boths variables it will help

Comment: Have you personally tracked the values of both variables?

Comment: Right now, for a weather station in CA, inspecting those values yields: sunriseDifference = 482 (minutes since sunrise) sunsetDifference = -118 (minutes since sunset)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem with the code and those values, so it must be something else... Did you try with a breakpoint on the first if to check the values there, and can you check which branch does it take?

Comment: @ChrisHolloway, in your question, you state that the code always results in "self.isNight = YES".  Are you testing that way, literally?  That's an assignment, not a boolean expression.  The correct test is "self.isNight == YES"... maybe post how you test the outcome of the conditional.

Comment: You need to give more examples.

Comment: @danh, you're correct, self.isNight == YES. Not assigned, that's what the code yields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with the comments that imply  the problem is tough to understand without the semantics from the weather service.  But if I were designing a weather service, those two params would always have different signs:

```
sunriseDifference > 0 && sunsetDifference < 0  means it's day
sunriseDifference < 0 && sunsetDifference > 0  means it's night
```

If I'm right about the meaning of the data, then the code can be corrected and simplified to:

```
self.isNight = sunriseDifference < 0 && sunsetDifference >= 0;
```

Comment: But if the signs were always different, his code would always set night as NO, which doesn't seem the case

Comment: @FabioRitrovato - yes, you're right.  kind of undermines my theory, doesn't it.

Comment: Just added extra information in the comments above.

Comment: @danh I accepted your answer. The actual culprit was an orphan line of code way down in the method implementation that set self.isNight to YES regardless of the logic we discussed above. Your simplification line above was very helpful as well, and I've incorporated it.